# electron BrowserWindow min height and width not working after hide() show() methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

1.Step

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1200,
  height: 700,
  center: true,
  'min-height': 700,
  'min-width': 1200,
  webPreferences: {nodeIntegration:true}});
mainWindow.loadURL(HOME_URL);
```

2.Step (some event occur and i want to temporary hide main window and show another(createFacebookWindow() fn is already loadingURL))

```
mainWindow.hide();



facebookWindow = require('./modules/auth/views.js').createFacebookWindow();

FB Window settings ({
                                              width: 1200,
                                              height: 700,
                                              center: true,
                                              'min-height': 700,
                                              'min-width': 1200,
                                               webPreferences: {nodeIntegration:false}})
```

3.Step (another event occur i destroy fb window and show main window)

```
 facebookWindow.close();

 facebookWindow.on('closed', function() {
    facebookWindow = null;
    mainWindow.show();
    //I tried below options it doesn't work
    //mainWindow.setSize(1200, 700);
    //mainWindow.setMinimumSize(1200, 700);
```

Summary:

So actually after these steps, when I show mainWindow back it doesn't remember mainWindow settings min-height and min-width are not working.

When facebookWindow is not opened, all is fine, so something must happening during switching with windows. Maybe something is done in wrong order ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can read the `BrowserWindow` documentation here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

- `maxWidth` instead `max-width`
- `minWidth` instead `min-width`
- `maxHeight` instead `max-height`
- `minHeight` instead `min-height`

Answer (score 3):

You can add `minWidth: 500` when initializing the `BrowserWindow`, like this:

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    minWidth:500,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
}
```

Note: The function `createWindow` is located in the `main.js` file, so you simply need to add `minWidth: value` inside the function.